# Why does postgres use more space for a time with timezone than a timestamp with timezone?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) on date/time data types state that `timestamp with timezone` takes 8 bytes, while `time with timezone` takes 12 bytes. They both have the same resolution (1 microsecond), and on the face of it `timestamp with timezone` is storing more information.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

I'm not planning on using `time with timezone` for reasons explained on the same page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`time with time zone` stores microseconds (8 bytes) and the time zone (4 bytes).  `timestamp with time zone` stores just the microseconds and converts the time zone at display time.  Because of the conceptual weirdness of the `time with time zone` type, the time zone needs to be stored explicitly.  You don't actually need 8 bytes to store the number of microseconds in a day, but 4 bytes wouldn't be enough.  If you really wanted to, you could probably devise a more compact storage format for `time with time zone`, but in practice nobody cares.